# Setting the optical size with beamer and fontspec

Tags: beamer, fontspec

I am using `fontspec` to select a font for my `beamer` presentation. The font I am using has different optical sizes, and `fontspec` takes full advantage of this. This is great for high resolution print, but for my presentation that is going to be displayed on a low-resolution screen, I would prefer not to use the display size for the title, just the regular optical size everywhere (and maybe even the caption size).

I have the following example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia, fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]{Minion Pro}

\title{How to set the optical size with beamer and fontspec?}
\author{Ruud v A}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `SizeFeatures` together with the `OpticalSize` option. For example:

```
\setmainfont[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional},
             SizeFeatures = {
               {Size = {-16}, OpticalSize = 8},
               {Size = {16-}, OpticalSize = 12}
             }]{Minion Pro}
```

Will use the caption optical size for regular text (with the `14pt` option), and the regular optical size for larger text. This works both with LuaLaTeX as well as XeLaTeX.